# Force Xcode4 to use different themes for header and implementation files

Tags: xcode, xcode4, syntax-highlighting

Is there some hack to force Xcode4 to use different themes for header and implementation files?

Comment: What are themes? You mean color schemes?

Comment: Just wondering: what's the motivation behind this? And yes, Eimantas, I'm pretty sure Fernando meant color schemes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify default header, you can modify file templates in: `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/` directory.